# Firebase file not found in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

All of a sudden my Firebase has stopped working within my Xcode project.

I am getting two errors. In my Viewcontroller.swift:

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

and in my Firebase.h file:

> 'FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h' file not found"

I think I know what the problem is but I do not know how to fix it. My FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h file is called FirebaseAnalytics/FirebaseAnalytics.h.icloud and I do not know how to remove the .icloud extension.

My framework looks like. [image: Frameworks]

My pod file looks like [image: Podfile]

So far I have tried: updating cocoapods and running pod install, and cleaning and rebuilding my project without any success.

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you integrate with or without cocopods? If without, did you follow the instructions for [integrating without cocopods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks)? Specifically, adding the ObjC linker flag and following the README instructions in the zip?

Comment: Why are you using use_frameworks! Documentation says specifically not to use that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using iCloud Drive.
A .iCloud extension means that iCloud have synced a placeholder file to you computer. A link to the original content stored in the cloud.

One scenario is that you tried to move a folder or the files to another location and this happened:

[image: icloud moving files]

> Your original file is gone. It’s gone from iCloud Drive, and it exists nowhere on your hard drive.
>
> In their place, is a file named FILENAME.original-extension.icloud. This file, only a couple kilobytes in size, is the placeholder that OS X uses to pretend that the file existed on your system. Your original file is gone. It’s gone from iCloud Drive, and it exists nowhere on your hard drive.

**Can OS X use them to download the originals from iCloud’s servers?**

Nope, they are gone.

Though it can be possible to recover the files from iCloud by login into the *web interface* and go *settings* and then click on *data & security*.

If this is only pod module files related content, then I think you should delete your pod modules and install them again.

I have found that using iCloud drive together with projects where a lot of files are dependent on each other are risky business. If you need backup of your files I suggest using a version control system like GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know exactly how the files were synched to iCloud as I never tried to back up anything. I was able to fix the problem with removing all pod 'Firebase' and pods that have to do with Firebase and re running pod install which removed them from my app. Then I added them back and ran pod install which reinstalled them and they no longer has the .icloud extension and no longer gave me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with removing all pod 'Firebase' and pods that have to do with Firebase and re running pod install which removed them from my app. Then I added them back and ran pod install which reinstalled them and they no longer has the .icloud extension and no longer gave me an error message

Comment: Thats what I said in my answer...why would you answer your own question when I already gave the correct answer?

Comment: your answer commented on iCloud yes which is obvious but it never told me to go delete all my pod files and then re install them with cocoa.

Comment: It does indeed. Read the second last paragraph again.